# css make img shown when hover a li

Tags: html, css

i have a page with many `LI` tags , and for any `LI` there is an image , this image is always hidden except when hovering the `LI`  the image have to be shown , i know i have to use 
`display:none`, but i don't know how can i used it on css on hovering `LI` , not hovering the img

## html

```
<?php
$pageNumber = $this->allQuestionsPageNumber;
$numberOfPages = $this->allQuestionsNumberOfPages;
$questions = $this->allQuestionsQuestionsForPage;
?>
<div id="allQuestions" class="container">
    <ul>
        <?php while ($row = $questions->fetch()) { ?>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <label>Question</label>
                    <?php echo $row['text']; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Answer</label>
                    <?php echo $row['answer']; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <img class="allqEdit"src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/images/Edit.png"/>
                </p>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li id="allQuestionsPages">
            <label>Page</label>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPages; $i++) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>Question/all/<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## css

```
.container ul li:hover{
    background-color: khaki;
}
```

Comment: why the downvote ? i tried and can't know the solution my self

Comment: i'm not one, wno downvote, but google can help you much faster than SO next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the following CSS

```
li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
li img {
    display: none;  
}
li:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```

You can see a live jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/GMnN4/)

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the `:hover` pseudo-class on the `li` selector:

```
li img { display: none; }
li:hover img { display: inline; }
```